# Two events changing every time button is clicked... but third event changes only on document load

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code lives at the bottom of my document, but it still stops working if I remove the `$(document).ready(function()` line. The first two events (dynamically filling ".currentRhythm_A" and "#currentLabelA") are working fine; they change every time I click the button. The third event, however -- dynamically filling "#playA" -- works only the first time I click the button. How am I coding that last line wrong? (I'm a js newbie here.) Many thanks!

EDIT: I should make clear that there are 100 other buttons like "6.1"--"4.2", "3.4", etc., which correspond to different rhythms. #playA gets filled correctly upon the FIRST button click—say, button 6.1—but, when I then click button 4.2, #playA stays filled with rhythm 6.1, rather than changing to rhythm 4.2. Divs ".currentRhythm_A" and "currentLabelA" DO keep changing with the button click. It's only #playA that doesn't keep changing, but rather maintains the value of whatever button was first clicked.

```
<div class="RM_rhythm">
    <audio id="6.1" preload='none'>
        <source class="straight" src='audio/6.1.mp3' type='audio/mpeg' /><source src='audio/6.1.ogg' type='audio/ogg' />
        <source class="swing" src='audio/swing/6.1.mp3' type='audio/mpeg' /><source src='audio/swing/6.1.ogg' type='audio/ogg' />
    </audio>
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('6.1').play()">&#x25b6;</button><a href="#" class="button">6-1</a><img src="images/RM-6.1.png" width="172" height="67" alt="6-1"></div>

<div class="currentSelection">
    <div class="playFeatured"><audio id="playA" preload='none'></audio>
    <button class="featuredAudio" onclick="document.getElementById('playA').play()">&#x25b6;</button></div> 
    <div class="selectedLabelA" id="currentLabelA">A</div>
    <div class="selectedRhythm currentRhythm_A" id="currentRhythm_A"></div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
$('.button').on('click', function() {
    var imagewanted = $(this).closest('.RM_rhythm').find('img').attr("src");
    $('.currentRhythm_A').html("<img src='" + imagewanted + "' />");
    var currentlabel = $(this).closest('.RM_rhythm').find('audio').attr("id");
    $('#currentLabelA').html(currentlabel);
    $('#playA').html("<source src='audio/" + currentlabel + ".mp3' type='audio/mpeg' /><source src='audio/" + currentlabel + ".ogg' type='audio/ogg' />");
    });
});
```

Comment: There's neither `.currentRhythm_A` nor `#currentLabelA` nor `#playA` in the code you provided. Please provide the full code.

Comment: Where is the element having id "playA". I don't find it in your HTML code.

Comment: Sorry, edited my question to add the relevant code.

Comment: I just tried your code, and it works fine for me (jQuery 2.1.4, Chromium v45). There's something you didn't show. It always fill the `#playA` element. Even if I remove `$(document).ready()` part. Is there anything in the console when you click the button few times?

Comment: @Timofey: It does fill the #playA element, but it never REFILLS it. (I see that I was not clear in my question above. There are 100 other buttons like "6.1"--"4.2", "3.4", etc., which correspond to different rhythms. #playA gets filled correctly upon the FIRST button click—say, button 6.1—but, when I then click button 4.2, #playA stays filled with rhythm 6.1, rather than changing to rhythm 4.2. I will add this explanation above. Thanks for your attention to this!

Comment: Yes, I got you. That's exactly what I tried and it *refills* just fine.

Comment: @Timofey, would you be willing to try it on my actual site and see if it works for you there? [link](http://www.yayforeverything.com/freescaling/rhythmetrics). Click "select your rhythms," select "measure A" and "2 notes per measure", and choose a rhythm. Click back into the main page and press the play button on measure A, and you should hear the correct rhythm. If you do it AGAIN now, and select a different measure (again in the "2" section, because those are the only audio files I've loaded), and click back out to the main page and press play, you'll still hear the FIRST rhythm you chose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, your jQuery code works just fine, and it indeed changes `source` tags in the `audio` element. The problem is that when you want to dynamically change the audio source you must call `.load()` method on the `audio` element. So your code has to be like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.button').on('click', function() {
    var imagewanted = $(this).closest('.RM_rhythm').find('img').attr("src");
    $('.currentRhythm_A').html("<img src='" + imagewanted + "' />");
    var currentlabel = $(this).closest('.RM_rhythm').find('audio').attr("id");
    $('#currentLabelA').html(currentlabel);
    $('#playA').html("<source src='audio/" + currentlabel + ".mp3' type='audio/mpeg' /><source src='audio/" + currentlabel + ".ogg' type='audio/ogg' />");
    $('#playA').load(); // note that line over here
    });
});
```